# Can't add more ETH to my object

Tags: solidity, truffle

there's something wrong with my code but I can't see what. I'm trying to create "pots" where you can add ETH inside.

```
mapping(uint => Pot) public pots;
mapping(uint => mapping(address => uint)) public contributionAmountForAddress; // Is a mapping(potIndex => mapping(0x0xxx => amountContributed))

struct Pot {
        string title;
        string description;
        address creator;
        PotStatus status;
    }
```

But when someone try to add MORE FUNDS to an existing one pot (the guys has already contributed), `contributeToPot`, it looks like my function is replacing the new contribution instead of adding it to the already existing contribution:

```
function contributeToPot(uint256 _potIdx) public payable returns (bool) {
        require(msg.value > 0, "The amount must be more than 0");
        require(pots[_potIdx].status == PotStatus.RUNNING, "The pot is closed, you cannot add more funds");

        // Pot storage potToFund = pots[_potIdx];
        if (contributionAmountForAddress[_potIdx][msg.sender] > 0) {
            contributionAmountForAddress[_potIdx][msg.sender] = contributionAmountForAddress[_potIdx][msg.sender] + msg.value;
        } else {
            contributionAmountForAddress[_potIdx][msg.sender] = msg.value;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Here are my tests:

```
const FIRST_CONTRIBUTION_IN_ETH = 2
const SECOND_CONTRIBUTION_IN_ETH = 1  

it('should contribute to a pot', async () => {
            const contributor = accounts[2]
            const amount = web3.utils.toWei(web3.utils.toBN(FIRST_CONTRIBUTION_IN_ETH), 'ether')
            await PiggyBank.contributeToPot(lastPotIndex.toNumber(), { from: contributor, value: amount })

            assert.equal(
                (await PiggyBank.contributionAmountForAddress.call(lastPotIndex, contributor)).toString(),
                amount.toString()
            )
        })

it ('should contribute even more to a pot', async () => {
            const contributor = accounts[3]
            const amount = web3.utils.toWei(web3.utils.toBN(SECOND_CONTRIBUTION_IN_ETH), 'ether')
            await PiggyBank.contributeToPot(lastPotIndex.toNumber(), { from: contributor, value: amount })
            
            const totalContributed = web3.utils.toWei(web3.utils.toBN(FIRST_CONTRIBUTION_IN_ETH + SECOND_CONTRIBUTION_IN_ETH), 'ether')
            // console.log(
            //     await PiggyBank.contributionAmountForAddress.call()
            // )
            assert.equal(
                (await PiggyBank.contributionAmountForAddress.call(lastPotIndex, contributor)).toString(),
                totalContributed.toString(),
            )
        })
```

The first one is correct, the second one not :(

```
1) Contract: PiggyBank
       Contribute to a pot
         should contribute even more to a pot:

      AssertionError: expected '1000000000000000000' to equal '3000000000000000000'
      + expected - actual

      -1000000000000000000
      +3000000000000000000
```

Someone have some ideas why is my test not passing ? It looks like the condition `if(contributionAmountForAddress[_potIdx][msg.sender] > 0) {` is always `false`. I don't know how can I log something in the code to better handle my error. Maybe my code structure is totally wrong ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Rather add a mapping to check if a user has contributed to the pool.
Then instead of using:

```
if(contributionAmountForAddress[_potIdx][msg.sender] > 0)
```

rather check if the new contribution mapping is true for that specific pool.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you mean. Can you elaborate with an example please ?